# Home and presenting institutes in Beamer

Tags: beamer, presentations

In my first slide, I want the name of my home university, which I can get by using `\institute` command. I also want the name of the institute of the university where I am presenting.

Is there a neat way to make both appear? The former also appears as an abbreviation in all slides, but the latter is restricted to the first slide.

Comment: Where do you want the abbreviation of the second university to appear in other slides? And which theme are you using?

Comment: Sometimes the `\date` command is 'misused` for this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: So no neat way available?

Comment: You can redefine the titlepage/maketitle command and define a command `\university` which works like the institute command and puts the university above or below the institute.  Would this be overkill for your needs?

Comment: @Bravo: `neat` is not uniquely defined ;-)

Comment: Where do you want the name of the other university to appear? Which theme are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick and dirty method: Use the `\date{...}` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\title{How not to be seen}


\author{Python Monty}

\institute{\inst{1}{Ministry of Silly Walks}}
\date{\today\par Talk held at Mr. Gumby Road 123 Lake Tahoe}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want a bit more space between the lines. How do I get it? Repeating \par?

Comment: @Bravo Add a skip. Use the optional argument too: `\date[\today]{\today\par\bigskip Talk held at Mr. Gumby Road 123 Lake Tahoe}` so the additional information won't go into an eventual footline.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for answering ;-)

Comment: @Bravo: No, repeated `\par` commands have no effect. Do as Gonzalo Medina suggested or use a skip of your own `\vskip\baselineskip` etc.

Comment: Upvoted just because of the Monty Python referece!